# Detecting when a circle really intersects a node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I use `ball.frame.intersects(bar.frame)`, where `ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: BALL_RADIUS)` and `bar = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: <Some CGSize object>)`

While this works, there is an invisible square in which the circle is inscribed. The diameter of the circle is the same as the side of the square. This square is what `ball.frame` is, so sometimes, the ball will act like it's intersecting the bar, but visually it's not.

[image]

In this screenshot you can see that the ball is stopped, and therefore the game is over because `ball.frame.intersects(bar.frame)` returned true, even though visually the ball isn't even touching the bar.

So how do I check if the ball is really intersecting the bar, and not if the ball's frame is intersecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpriteKit has decently powerful collision detection in its physics subsystem — you don't have to roll your own.

Create `SKPhysicsBody` objects for the ball and the bars, using [`init(circleOfRadius:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithCircleOfRadius:) for the former and [`init(rectangleOfSize:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithRectangleOfSize:) for the latter.

Then, you can either:

1. Drive all the movement yourself, and use `SKPhysics` only to test for collisions. In this case you need to set your scene's `physicsWorld.gravity` to the zero vector, and call [`allContactedBodies()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsBody/allContactedBodies) on the ball when you want to see if it's contacting a bar.
2. Let `SKPhysics` drive the movement, by setting velocities or applying impulses. In this case you'll need to set a contact delegate for your physics world, and then you'll get a callback whenever a collision occurs.

For more details on either approach, see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW1).

Comment: Thanks. I used approach #1. Adding a physics body to the ball and the bar not only fixed the problem, but also added a cool effect where the ball, when hitting the bar, pushes the bar a little.

Comment: Yep—and if you don't like that effect or want to tweak it, you can adjust the properties on either body.

Comment: Oh definitely. I need to do a lot of experimentation with the builtin physics tools to see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

After detecting that ball frame intersects box frame:

- Determine the radius of the ball
- Determine the point on the line that is the edge of the ball from the center of the ball to the edge of the box. (Hint: pythagorean theorem - hypotenuse = radius)
- Is this point inside the box's rect?
- Repeat for each point in the box.